# Undo all locally made changes in git bash session

Tags: git, bash, session, github, restore

is there any way to restore all locally deleted files in a git bash session?
I made a backup folder, but git deleted it together with the original folder.

I need to restore all the files listed after the `git rm -rf *` command.
Can't turn off my computer until they're back.

Sorry for the long text, but in the following I'll show all commands I tried to use in this session.

---

```
Stefan@DESKTOP-97STV3T MINGW64 /c/xampp/htdocs/Git/Pokenizer (master|REBASE 1/3)
$ git branch -D master
git rm -rf *Deleted branch master (was d30697f).

Stefan@DESKTOP-97STV3T MINGW64 /c/xampp/htdocs/Git/Pokenizer (master|REBASE 1/3)
$ git checkout --orphan master
Switched to a new branch 'master'

Stefan@DESKTOP-97STV3T MINGW64 /c/xampp/htdocs/Git/Pokenizer (master|REBASE 1/3)
$ git rm -rf *
rm 'README.md'
rm 'bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.css'
rm 'bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.css.map'
rm 'bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css'
rm 'bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css'
rm 'bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css.map'
rm 'bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css'
rm 'bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot'
rm 'bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg'
rm 'bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf'
rm 'bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff'
rm 'bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2'
rm 'bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js'
rm 'bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js'
rm 'bootstrap/js/npm.js'
rm 'core/.DS_Store'
rm 'core/._.DS_Store'
rm 'core/ajax/ajax_handler.php'
rm 'core/classes/.DS_Store'
rm 'core/classes/._.DS_Store'
rm 'core/classes/Config.php'
rm 'core/classes/Cookie.php'
rm 'core/classes/Data.php'
rm 'core/classes/Database.php'
rm 'core/classes/Hash.php'
rm 'core/classes/Input.php'
rm 'core/classes/Redirect.php'
rm 'core/classes/Session.php'
rm 'core/classes/Token.php'
rm 'core/classes/Transformer.php'
rm 'core/classes/User.php'
rm 'core/classes/Validate.php'
rm 'core/functions/.DS_Store'
rm 'core/functions/._.DS_Store'
rm 'core/functions/login.php'
rm 'core/functions/register.php'
rm 'core/functions/sanitize.php'
rm 'core/init.php'
rm 'favicon.ico'
rm 'fontello/LICENSE.txt'
rm 'fontello/README.txt'
rm 'fontello/config.json'
rm 'fontello/css/animation.css'
rm 'fontello/css/fontello-codes.css'
rm 'fontello/css/fontello-embedded.css'
rm 'fontello/css/fontello-ie7-codes.css'
rm 'fontello/css/fontello-ie7.css'
rm 'fontello/css/fontello.css'
rm 'fontello/demo.html'
rm 'fontello/font/fontello.eot'
rm 'fontello/font/fontello.svg'
rm 'fontello/font/fontello.ttf'
rm 'fontello/font/fontello.woff'
rm 'images/006-mega-x.gif'
rm 'images/MegaGlurakX.jpg'
rm 'images/Pokeball.png'
rm 'index.php'
rm 'info.txt'
rm 'javaScripts/main.js'
rm 'logout.php'
rm 'pokenizer.sql'
rm 'slices/base/body_end.inc.php'
rm 'slices/base/body_start.inc.php'
rm 'slices/base/head.inc.php'
rm 'slices/base/html_end.inc.php'
rm 'slices/base/html_start.inc.php'
rm 'slices/base/page_end.inc.php'
rm 'slices/base/page_start.inc.php'
rm 'slices/modals/front/login_modal.inc.php'
rm 'slices/modals/front/signup_modal.inc.php'
rm 'slices/sites/start.php'
rm 'slices/sites/user.php'
rm 'slices/tests/profile.php'
rm 'slices/tests/start.php'
rm 'slices/widgets/front/heading.inc.php'
rm 'slices/widgets/front/navbar.inc.php'
rm 'slices/widgets/front/panels.inc.php'
rm 'slices/widgets/front/welcome.inc.php'
rm 'slices/widgets/loggedIn/header_options.inc.php'
rm 'slices/widgets/loggedIn/left_sidebar.inc.php'
rm 'slices/widgets/loggedOut/left_sidebar.inc.php'
rm 'styleSheets/activities.css'
rm 'styleSheets/contentArea/main.css'
rm 'styleSheets/front/main.css'
rm 'styleSheets/predefinitions.css'
rm 'styleSheets/profile.css'
rm 'users/0f2586f30af8a59f3fe278efc41f16f2/profile.jpg'
rm 'users/0f2586f30af8a59f3fe278efc41f16f2/profileFull.jpg'
rm 'users/36d38ab6c36f095dff785cf531e67ce4/profile.jpg'
rm 'users/36d38ab6c36f095dff785cf531e67ce4/profileFull.jpg'

Stefan@DESKTOP-97STV3T MINGW64 /c/xampp/htdocs/Git/Pokenizer (master|REBASE 1/3)
$ ^C

Stefan@DESKTOP-97STV3T MINGW64 /c/xampp/htdocs/Git/Pokenizer (master|REBASE 1/3)
$ git reset (--hard) HEAD~1
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Stefan@DESKTOP-97STV3T MINGW64 /c/xampp/htdocs/Git/Pokenizer (master|REBASE 1/3)
$ git reset --hard HEAD~1
fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD~1': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'

Stefan@DESKTOP-97STV3T MINGW64 /c/xampp/htdocs/Git/Pokenizer (master|REBASE 1/3)
$ git reset

Stefan@DESKTOP-97STV3T MINGW64 /c/xampp/htdocs/Git/Pokenizer (master|REBASE 1/3)
$ git checkout --$(git ls-files -d)
fatal: You are on a branch yet to be born

Stefan@DESKTOP-97STV3T MINGW64 /c/xampp/htdocs/Git/Pokenizer (master|REBASE 1/3)
$ git reset --hard

Stefan@DESKTOP-97STV3T MINGW64 /c/xampp/htdocs/Git/Pokenizer (master|REBASE 1/3)
$ git reset --hard d30697f
HEAD is now at d30697f updated

Stefan@DESKTOP-97STV3T MINGW64 /c/xampp/htdocs/Git/Pokenizer (master|REBASE 1/3)
$ git checkout HEAD C:\xampp\htdocs\Git\Pokenizer
fatal: C:xampphtdocsGitPokenizer: 'C:xampphtdocsGitPokenizer' is outside repository

Stefan@DESKTOP-97STV3T MINGW64 /c/xampp/htdocs/Git/Pokenizer (master|REBASE 1/3)
$ git checkout HEAD

Stefan@DESKTOP-97STV3T MINGW64 /c/xampp/htdocs/Git/Pokenizer (master|REBASE 1/3)
$ git checkout HEAD^
Note: checking out 'HEAD^'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

  git checkout -b <new-branch-name>

HEAD is now at bea5a92... updated

Stefan@DESKTOP-97STV3T MINGW64 /c/xampp/htdocs/Git/Pokenizer (master|REBASE 1/3)
$ git checkout -b newbranch
Switched to a new branch 'newbranch'

Stefan@DESKTOP-97STV3T MINGW64 /c/xampp/htdocs/Git/Pokenizer (master|REBASE 1/3)
$ git reset -- Pokenizer/

Stefan@DESKTOP-97STV3T MINGW64 /c/xampp/htdocs/Git/Pokenizer (master|REBASE 1/3)
$ git checkout -- Pokenizer/
error: pathspec 'Pokenizer/' did not match any file(s) known to git.

Stefan@DESKTOP-97STV3T MINGW64 /c/xampp/htdocs/Git/Pokenizer (master|REBASE 1/3)
$ git ls-files –deleted

Stefan@DESKTOP-97STV3T MINGW64 /c/xampp/htdocs/Git/Pokenizer (master|REBASE 1/3)
$ git reset HEAD

Stefan@DESKTOP-97STV3T MINGW64 /c/xampp/htdocs/Git/Pokenizer (master|REBASE 1/3)
$ git checkout -- lib bin
error: pathspec 'lib' did not match any file(s) known to git.
error: pathspec 'bin' did not match any file(s) known to git.

Stefan@DESKTOP-97STV3T MINGW64 /c/xampp/htdocs/Git/Pokenizer (master|REBASE 1/3)
$ git ls-files -d | xargs git checkout --

Stefan@DESKTOP-97STV3T MINGW64 /c/xampp/htdocs/Git/Pokenizer (master|REBASE 1/3)
$ git ls-files -d | xargs git checkout -
Note: checking out 'bea5a92f5d9dca86ce34149c0ae9ba9eb42fd25a'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

  git checkout -b <new-branch-name>

HEAD is now at bea5a92... updated
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you've got conflicts with a rebase from the start

Try these commands

git rebase --abort

git reset --hard HEAD

Check the log to see the commit you'd like to roll back to

git log --oneline --graph --decorate --all

Comment: I tried the commands and got this output: `Stefan@DESKTOP-97STV3T MINGW64 /c/xampp/htdocs/Git/Pokenizer (master|REBASE 1/3)
$ git rebase --abort

Stefan@DESKTOP-97STV3T MINGW64 /c/xampp/htdocs/Git/Pokenizer (master)
$ git reset --hard HEAD
HEAD is now at d30697f updated

Stefan@DESKTOP-97STV3T MINGW64 /c/xampp/htdocs/Git/Pokenizer (master)
$ git log --oneline --graph --decorate --all
* d30697f (HEAD -> master, origin/master) updated
* bea5a92 (newbranch) updated
* b26bc2d updated
* 45cd901 updated
* ab1d5f4 added project files
* 373e232 Update README.md
* 8cecd13 lol
* a47ca75 Initial commit`

Comment: before deleting all the files I committed, but I don't see the commit in the log list.